# Вопрос про мягкий знак и склонение числительных

Tags: орфография, синтаксис, согласование

Здравствуйте. Два вопроса:

1. Как правильно писать *понравиться* в выражении "Чтобы понравиться..." Нужен ли мягкий?
2. Когда спрашивают, какой у вас номер, как правильно ответить: *тридцать пять* или *тридцать пятый*?

Comment: Два столь разных вопроса надо задавать в двух разных темах. Впрочем, ответ Вам дали.

Answer (score 1):

1) Чтобы (что сдела**ть**? - глагол совершенного вида) *понрави**ть**ся*.

2) Можно и так и так.

> Какой у вас номер?
>
> 1. Тридцать пять (несогласованное определение; ср.: *Мой номер - тридцать пять*).
> 2. Тридцать пятый (согласованное определение; ср.: *Мой номер **(какой?)** тридцать пятый*).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы (что сделать? - глагол совершенного вида) понравиться. В данном сочетании глагол "понравиться" пишется с Ь, потому что в вопросе чтобы (что сделать?) понравиться есть Ь Главное, вопрос не должен "висеть" в воздухе. Его обязательно нужно задавать от одного слова к другому.
На вопрос "какой у Вас номер?", я думаю, будет уместно ответить "тридцать пятый", используя порядковое числительное, отвечающее на вопрос КОТОРЫЙ?